# Django admin inline model concurrent deletions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Lets say I am viewing an admin page for a model, that has some inline model displayed. I change some main model field, and hit save. However, before that, someone else is viewing the same page and deletes one of the inlined models.
Now when the first one saves, he will get a bunch of random errors, in some cases it will try to create the deleted inline model again, in some other cases, some validation error with an empty string happens, and if you hit save again, some multi key value dict error is raised.

How do I property handle a case like this? Django doesn't seem to be smart enough to detect the model was deleted and perform no action.

Comment: Checking this deeper, it seems that if you save and any of the inline models was deleted from somewhere else, or even changed so that it no longer belongs to the main model, django will report the 'id' field as a changed field, resulting in either a very weird validation error or django detecting it as a new instance and try to create it. This is on django 1.7.8 btw. I can't believe this is not handled properly anywhere.

Comment: Override the save function in admin page and get model state just before saving. If model changed you can do some validations or prompt mesage with new values instead of saving

Comment: That is something I was trying to avoid, doing so would require me to make a custom form and add custom code on every model I'm using to check for an 'id' change (which is usually what is detected as changed when a deleted object is going to be saved), I'm hoping for a more general option